# error while searching about MaxPrice in ArrayList

Tags: java

I have three classes: Book - Course - CourseBooks.

CourseBooks class have two attributes:

```
private Course course; 
private ArrayList<Book> books;
```

with setters, getters, constructor, toString method.

I need to write a method to get the Book with the MaxPrice of the list, this is the code:

```
protected Book getMaxPrice() {
    Book max= books.get(0);  
    for(int i=1; i< books.size(); i++) { 
        if(books.get(i) > max) { 
        max = books.get(i);     
        } // end if if 
    } // end of for
```

the IF Statement is giving me an error:
**The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) classes.Book, classes.Book**
so, what's wrong with the IF statement?

Comment: '>' operator does not work on Objects. In if statement you are directly comparing two objects of book using '>' which is not allowed.  If you could include complete Book class as well then we can provide a working solution because you new here at stack overflow.

Comment: Does your Book object has an attribute called "price". If yes, you can set MaxPrice = 0 and then update it when books.get(i).price > MaxPrice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can't use `>` on object of a class.

```java
protected Book getMaxPrice() {
    Book max= books.get(0);  
    for(int i=1; i< books.size(); i++) { 
        if(books.get(i) > max) { //how to comapare book?
        max = books.get(i);     
        } // end if if 
    } // end of for
```

Create method that compares book with given parameter book.

PS. You should use `Collections.max` for searching maximum value. You can create [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compares 2 books by some value and it will sort it